# How to prevent leaking Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, leakcanary, android-memory, android-fragment-manager

I have the following Activity:

```
class SwitchFragAct extends AppCompatActivity {
  Fragment a;
  Fragment b;

  onClickSwitchFrags(View v) {
    FragmentManager mgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFrag = mgr.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_to_swap);
    
    if (currentFrag == a) {
       mgr.beginTransaction().detach(a).attach(b).commit();
    } else if (currentFrag == b) {
       mgr.beginTransaction().detach(b).attach(a).commit();
    }
  }
}
```

So leak canary will complain the that the unattached fragment is leaking (e.g. @ SwitchFragAct#a) . What is my alternative to make sure it doesn't leak? I think I need to use attach/detach so the state is still being saved. I think the only alternative is to recreate the fragment every time. Currently there aren't any mechanisms to do so in that fragment where I can pass in saved state.

Comment: Instead of saving the instances of each fragment, attach a tag to each of them when performing a transaction. Then you can compare the tags rather than comparing the instances.

Answer (score 2):

Use replace. The `replace` method removes the current fragment and adds a new fragment in its place.

```java
class SwitchFragAct extends AppCompatActivity {
  Fragment a;
  Fragment b;

  onClickSwitchFrags(View v) {
    FragmentManager mgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFrag = mgr.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_to_swap);
    
    if (currentFrag == a) {
       mgr.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_to_swap, b).commit();
    } else if (currentFrag == b) {
       mgr.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_to_swap, a).commit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT generated answers are not allowed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1